# LDAP and Symfony2: authentication and retrieving all users and groups

Tags: symfony, authentication, active-directory, ldap

We'd like to integrate our SaaS with LDAP/AD.

The integration will be needed both for authentication and to define roles/clearances. So what we need to do is having a list of the groups in LDAP server and mimick them on our system to define the clearances for each.

Of course, having some clients using LDAP and some others not, we'll need to authenticate against several servers (as [this bundle](https://github.com/DarwinOnLine/DoLLdapBundle) does) plus we need the "load all users/roles given a server".

What's also not clear to me in relation to that bundle is: how do we define when authenticating against server1, when server2 and when skipping LDAP/AD authentication altogether?

Thank you

Comment: It will not be very easy to do (load all users/roles given a server). Basically the ldap component will check if auth is ok or not regarding how you have configured it (security.yml).